# Track stolen android phone with IMEI using google

Tags: android

Since, Google knows the IMEI of every phone with a gmail account, (I'm assuming you know the 'find my phone' by google), can I possibly or can google possibly check if another account is using the same IMEI?

Ex.

My phone, 'A', have an account name 'barney'.
Phone 'A' is stolen and is reset by some thief. Of course  IMEI of the phone 'A' is still intact. When the thieves log in with another account name 'devil', Google now have it's IMEI.

This is where it gets interesting. Since there are two account with similar IMEI, Barney can look up his phone again without his (barney) account in Phone  'A'.

Is it possible for google to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your carrier will have a record of your IMEI number. If you report your phone as lost/stolen, you can have your device blocked from accessing that carriers network, but that's about it.

GPS services for tracking devices need an account that is registered and active on the device (e.g iCloud/Google) to work. If you're using an Android device you can pull an [Android device configuration service](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9021432) report to look at network data, but this would only be useful if the phone still had your profile intact.

I know that getting something valuable stolen really hurts, it's a sickening feeling. The best thing you can do is change any passwords for services you has associated with the device and buy another phone. Don't feel bummed out, losing things happens to everyone.